# How to increase the height of the Arrow in mql4 indicator

Tags: mql4, mql5

I ploted some arrows in my MQL4 indicator so i am able to increase the width of the arrow but i want to increase the height of the arrow only so please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The arrow symbols do not have separate adjust-ability in width and height, its just 'size'. An option would be to plot the arrow head, then draw a trend line object vertically above it to the length that you want.

Answer (score 1):

### MQL4 solution

Indicator can instruct an <kbd>Arrow</kbd> instance to have "bigger" size using `OBJPROP_WIDTH` instance attribute:

```
{ string                        anInterimObjNAME = "S" + sSellCntr;
  ObjectCreate(                 anInterimObjNAME, OBJ_ARROW, 0,      Time[0], Bid );
  ObjectSet(                    anInterimObjNAME, OBJPROP_COLOR,     Red );
  if ( Action == 0 ) ObjectSet( anInterimObjNAME, OBJPROP_ARROWCODE, 1 );
  if ( Action <  0 ) ObjectSet( anInterimObjNAME, OBJPROP_ARROWCODE, 5 );
  ObjectSet(                    anInterimObjNAME, OBJPROP_WIDTH,     1 ); //<--
//ObjectSet(                    anInterimObjNAME, OBJPROP_WIDTH,     32 );//<--
}
```

### New-MQL4 extension

Since Build 509+ there started to be new and new modifications of the MQL4 language syntax. So far, many times opening an integrated help system launches just another language update, so be carefull on coding limits, suddenly changed or unsupported syntax elements and even check several new syntax constructs. This is the life as it goes.

So, for the `OBJ_ARROW`, there is a possibility to extend it's size beyond a value of 5, which is ( as of Build 670 ) a limit for a manual GUI entry.

Help says:

```
        Large arrows (more than 5) can only be created
        by setting the appropriate OBJPROP_WIDTH property value
        when writing a code in MetaEditor.
```

So, manually you still cannot enter more than 5, but via MQL4 code, you can go BIGGER :o)